# Arraylist element index before and after Collections.shuffle in java

Tags: java, arraylist

How can i compare before and after shuffle arraylist element and get the position of original arraylist?

Comment: I am trying to create an android quiz app. Eveything is went ok. but when it comes to count correct and wrong answer, I am able to count correct answer and add up once but if i select wrong answer then i counted up that much times i have stored answer in array. I just want to count my wrong answer also once.. Therefore what I am thinking is get a UserSelected radio button answer first in one side. On other side, i have shuffled arraylist, if i can get the original index number of an shuffled array i can pass that index value to answer arraylist and get specific answer string and compare them.

Comment: Could you give an example list and show what you are expecting to see?

Comment: public void quizQuestionAndAnswer() {
        for (i = 0; i < question.length; i++) {
            quiz.add(new QuestionAndAnswer(question[i], answer[i], distractorList.subList(i * 3, (i + 1) * 3)));           
            System.out.println("Before shuffle quiz index:" + " " + i + " is " + quiz.get(i));
        }
         Collections.shuffle(quiz);
        System.out.println("ArrayList after shuffle" + quiz); //Display ArrayList after shuffle}

Comment: This is my arraylist, from here i want to get index of original quiz

Comment: Is there a another way to compare randomly generated radiogroup right radiobutton answer to specific answer that stored in array. Currently i am comparing and each user selected radio button to all array answers, hence when selecting wrong answer that gives me back no. of array elements times wrong answer. If you could please help me out with this problem, I am stuck here since many days and already have done a lot of research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to hold on to the original position of the object you need to make a copy of the arraylist before you shuffle it.  And then use indexOf